# Как сделать для прямоугольной матрицы?

Tags: c

Как сделать перебор псевдодиагоналей для прямоугольной матрицы?

```
for(i = 0; i < N; ++i){
    for(j = i; j >= 0; --j)
        printf("%d ", mat[j][i - j]);
    puts("");
}

for(j = 1; j < N; ++j){
    for(i = j; i < N; ++i)
        printf("%d ", mat[N - 1 - (i - j)][i]);
    puts("");
}
```

P.S. Это алгоритм перебора псевдодиагоналей для квадратной матрицы

Comment: Ваш вопрос плавно перетекает из с в математику. А что такое а псевдодиагонали  для прямоугольной матрицы?

Comment: Нарисуйте рисунок, для себя хотя бы. Лучше два. 1-для квадратной. 2-для прямоугольной. Тогда и вопрос возможно ответ сам напросится.